# SQL Merge two rows from two tables

Tags: sql, cursor

I have two tables, and I'm trying to get data from both of them into a single temp table using cursor.

Tg and WTg are different labels for two different systems that represent the same thing. So you could think of Tg as "Laundry Basket" while WTg is "Basket of Laundry". The goal is to compare the AVG values of the two tables. I'm using a cursor because that's how the query was dumped on me. I was under the impression a cursor would be desirable and quicker because of the size of the tables we're using (150,000+ unique Wtg/Tg's with 100's of thousands of values each)

I'm not particularly emotionally attached to this method, so if you have a suggestion, feel free to correct me.

A snip from my query reads:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM tgListcur INTO @TgName, @W_TgName  
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0  
BEGIN  

Insert into #Results (WTg, W_AvgVal)  
select TgName, AVG(Value) as Average  
from SQLTABLE1  
      where TgName = @W_TgName  
            and wwRetrievalMode = 'Delta'  
            and wwResolution = 0  
            and Datetime > @StartTime  
            and datetime < @EndTime  
            and value IS NOT NULL  
Group By TgName  

Insert into #Results (Tg, P_AvgVal)  
Select Tag, AVG(Value) as Average  
from SQLTABLE2  
    where Tag = @TgName  
    and Time > @StartTime  
    and Time < @EndTime  
Group by Tag  

FETCH NEXT FROM tgListcur INTO @TgName, @W_TgName  
END
```

And it's giving me:

> ```
>        WTg       |      Tg        |        W_AvgVal       |        P_AvgVal
> ________________________________________________________________________________
>    Data1         |      NULL      |          50           |          NULL  
> ________________________________________________________________________________    
>     NULL         |     Value1     |          NULL         |           50
> ________________________________________________________________________________
>    Data2         |      NULL      |          70           |          NULL       
> ________________________________________________________________________________  
>     NULL         |     Value2     |          NULL         |           70
> ________________________________________________________________________________
>    Data3         |      NULL      |          60           |          NULL       
> ________________________________________________________________________________  
>     NULL         |     Value3     |          NULL         |           60
> ________________________________________________________________________________
>    Data4         |      NULL      |          12           |          NULL       
> ________________________________________________________________________________
> ```

```
etc. etc.
```

I'd obviously like to get the nulls out and merge the two tables like:

> ```
>        WTg       |      Tg        |        W_AvgVal       |        P_AvgVal
> ________________________________________________________________________________
>    Data1         |      Value1    |          50           |          50
> ________________________________________________________________________________    
>    Data2         |      Value2    |          70           |          70
> ________________________________________________________________________________
>    Data3         |      Value3    |          60           |          60       
> ________________________________________________________________________________
> ```

Etc.

I'm new to SQL, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing here guy? What value does the cursor serve?

Comment: The first question is, how to match rows in the SQLTABLE1 to their pairs in SQLTABLE2? How are `Tg` and `WTg` related?